# How can I get all quads to triangulate the same way

Tags: modeling, mesh

When triangulating the mesh it does this mirrored effect where the tris seem to switch direction at some points. Is there a way to make that all go the same way?

[image]

In other words. I need all the edges that separate the quads to go the same way (I've done this manually below). Their must be a better way to do this than with the knife tool.

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Select a **loop**
Do **Triangulate Faces**
Quad Method to **Fixed**

[image]
[image]